# Pandas set empty values in column based on its type

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying read an excel with below values:

[image]

I need a generic way to convert  all NA to 'Not Available' and empty values in column to either 0 or "" based on its type.

Example:

[image]

I used below code to do this:

```
df=pd.read_excel(price_excel,sheet_name=0,na_values='NA',keep_default_na=False)
df=df.replace(np.nan, 'Not Available', regex=True)
# changing nan values of int and float to 0 and string to ""
col_with_data_type={}
for j,i in zip(df.columns,df.dtypes):
    if(i=='int64' or i=='float64'):
        col_with_data_type[j]=0
    else:
        col_with_data_type[j]=""
df.fillna(value=col_with_data_type,inplace=True)
```

I am able to convert 'NA' to 'Not Available' , but not empty empty value to 0 or "".

Currently my dataframe look like this:

[image]

Please help me to resolve this issue.